# Can I receive incoming mail with Google App Engine on a non-default version?

Tags: google-app-engine, email, incoming-mail

Google App Engine allows for multiple version to be deployed concurrently, one of which is the default.

You can access non-default versions via HTTP (and apparently also via XMPP) using a special URL.

Is it possible to send email to a non-default version as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is not a supported feature since the Mail documentation about this aspect is missing and there's an open issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2311#c1).

Anyway, if the mails are handled like XMPP addresses

> Each version of an app has its own set
>   of XMPP addresses in the following
>   format:
>
> anything@version.latest.app-id.appspotchat.com
>
> If App Engine receives a message for
>   an address in this format, it is
>   routed to the corresponding version of
>   the app (if that version still
>   exists).

you could try with:

> foo@version.latest.app-id.appspotmail.com

**EDIT:**
[This post](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/b944df259c222d81) confirms that you CAN'T do it.

Comment: You would figure after almost 6 years, there would be a solution or a valid workaround for this. Anyone have anything?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but this has been solved for:

Send e-mail to the specific version by @version-dot-app-name-here.appspotmail.com

E.g.,
mail@1-0-1-dot-app-name-here.appspotmail.com